# Keyboard Sensor - how to put NULL (NO KEYS PRESSED)

Tags: animation

Keyboard Sensor - how to put NULL (NO KEYS PRESSED), i am unsure of how to change it to NULL or something so i can add idle animation

Comment: maybe you can use an "always" sensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your Logic Bricks like this:
[image]